# Update specific cell in gridview using an edit button?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to edit TaskName and DueDate in a specific cell in the gridview when i clicked the edit button. Anyone can provide some code that i can put inside the if(e.CommandName == "Edit")?

This is my code in Checklist.aspx.cs:

```
protected void gvAddTask_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{    
    int i = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());    
    string CheckListId = gvAddTask.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text;

    if(e.CommandName == "Edit")
    {

    }

    if (e.CommandName == "Del")
    {

        BlChecklist blChecklist = new BlChecklist();
        blChecklist.DeleteChecklist(int.Parse(gvAddTask.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text));
        gvAddTask.DataBind();
    }

}
```

This is my gridview code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvAddTask" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%"

EmptyDataText="There are no tasks!" GridLines="Horizontal" 

OnRowCommand="gvAddTask_RowCommand" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" 

CellPadding="4" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#336666" 

BorderStyle="Double" BorderWidth="3px" style="margin-top: 0px">

<Columns>

<asp:BoundField DataField="CheckListId" HeaderText="CheckListId" 

HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ReadOnly="True">

<HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></HeaderStyle>

</asp:BoundField>

<asp:BoundField DataField="TaskName" HeaderText="TaskName" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">

<HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></HeaderStyle>

</asp:BoundField>

<asp:BoundField DataField="DueDate" HeaderText="DueDate" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">

<HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></HeaderStyle>

</asp:BoundField>

<asp:ButtonField  ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"/>

<asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Del" Text="Delete" />

</Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by inline edit? I want to edit directly inside the gridview

Answer (score 0):

You have to use asp:TemplateField for TaskName , DueDate and button.
Then on Rowcommand event u can use findcontrol property to change the value.

Also look at this link : http://forums.asp.net/t/1528797.aspx/1

On Rowcommad event You can use below code.

```
if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
    {
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        GridViewRow row = gviewRetailers.Rows[index];
        string CheckListId =  row.Cells[0].Text;

        string sql="update tblname set TaskName ="u want" ,DueDate ="U wnat" where id = CheckListId "; // for example only use can use your update query

       // Update value and Bind grid again

    }
```

Thanks,
Hitesh

Comment: So I need to create both boundfield and templatefield for TaskName , DueDate and button?

Comment: Have looked at the link,I can get the values of a specific cell. But when I edit the values, there is no changes made

Comment: Ok. Now Update database table's value for those fields using above value in method and again bind grid.